# Manipular uma classe do tipo Object

Tags: java, android

tenho a seguinte situação muito complexa (pelo menos para mim).

Tenho uma classe Pessoa (Os dados são fictícios para melhor entendimento, mas a ideia é a mesma) assim:

```
public class Pessoa { 
   private int codigo;
   private String nome;
   // Geters e seters 
}
```

Agora eu preciso criar uma outra classe com o nome Fmt. Essa classe será genérica, ou seja, pode receber qualquer tipo de objeto como parâmetro, por exemplo Pessoa, Pagamento, Locacao, etc. A classe Fmt teria que ter esses métodos

```
public class Fmt {
   public String getAtributo(Objct obj){
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os nomes dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
      Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “codigo, nome”*/
   }

   public String getValores(Objct obj){
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os valores dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “23, Sabrina” */
   }


   public String getTipos(Objct obj){
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os tipos dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
      Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “int, string”*/
      }
   }
```

Todo esse trabalho será usado para persistir em um web server.

Gostaria de pelo menos ter um norte de como começar (se isso for possível é claro, rsrs).

Comment: Qual a dificuldade?

Comment: Dá uma olhada na API de reflection. É a melhor forma de acessar métodos e atributos de classes Olha esse link http://rodrigosasaki.com/2013/07/12/api-de-reflection-do-java/ Abraço

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma implementação possível, para atributos privados e tipos primitivos, será:

```
public class Fmt {

    public static String getAtributos(Object obj){
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os nomes dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
      Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “codigo, nome”*/
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Class classe = obj.getClass();
        Field[] fields = classe.getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println(fields.length);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if( Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
                if(result.length() > 0)result.append(", ");
                result.append(field.getName());
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String getValores(Object obj) {
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os valores dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “23, Sabrina” */

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Class classe = obj.getClass();
        Field[] fields = classe.getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println(fields.length);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if( Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
                Object value = null;
                field.setAccessible(true);
                try {
                    value = field.get(obj);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if(result.length() > 0)result.append(", ");
                if(value == null){
                    result.append("null");
                }
                else {
                    result.append(value.toString());
                }
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    public static String getTipos(Object obj){
      /*Esse método tem a função de me trazer os tipos dos atributos que tem na classe do tipo objeto enviado.
      Por exemplo, se a classe passada for a Pessoa, ele teria que me retornar uma String mais assim: “int, string”*/

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        Class classe = obj.getClass();
        Field[] fields = classe.getDeclaredFields();
        System.out.println(fields.length);
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if( Modifier.isPrivate(field.getModifiers())) {
                if(result.length() > 0)result.append(", ");
                result.append(field.getType().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa();
String result;
result = Fmt.getAtributos(pessoa);
Log.d("FMT", result);
result = Fmt.getTipos(pessoa);
Log.d("FMT", result);
result = Fmt.getValores(pessoa);
Log.d("FMT", result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer uma Reflection, de uma pesquisada sobre isso, abaixo montei um exemplo para você, eu pego todos os atributos da classe Pessoa.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pessoa n = new Pessoa();
    Class classe = Pessoa.class;
    Field[] atributos = classe.getDeclaredFields(); 
    System.out.println(atributos.length);
    for (Field atributo : classe.getDeclaredFields()) {         
            System.out.println(atributo.getName());      
    }

}
```

Abs

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou muito, deixei meu sistema muito mais dinâmico e reutilizável!